How to pass data Fragments Recyclerview to another Activity Recyclerview , parcelable, json , kotlin
How to display data from one Fragment's recyclerView to another activity's recyclerView using parcelable from local Json File. I want to pass data HomeFragment recyclerview to Activity RecyclerView but I don't know where I am doing wrong. and Activity is loading blank, data is not passing and my recyclerview not loading. Please help me.
My App Screenshots
Home Fragment Screen
ChpterActivity (second Activity) Screen
My Local Json File
"items": [
    {
      "bookName": "Basic Grammar",
      "imageUrl": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1MVDiLI3AmfbpZzuMi87LZ30JSUU-wI6A",
      "content": [
        {
          "chapterName": "Definition",
          "details": [
            "<p><strong>Definition of English Grammar</p>"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }

BooksData (My data class)
data class BooksData(
    val bookName: String,
    val imageUrl: String,
    val items: ArrayList<ChapterData> = ArrayList()
) :
    Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readString().toString(),
        parcel.readString().toString(),
        arrayListOf<ChapterData>().apply {
            parcel.readList(this, ChapterData::class.java.classLoader)
        }
    )

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(bookName)
        parcel.writeString(imageUrl)
        parcel.writeList(items)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<BooksData> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): BooksData {
            return BooksData(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<BooksData?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}

Home Fragment (recycler list item click listener and ParseJson)
private fun initListener() {

        // recycler list item click listener

        val adapter = bookAdapter
        adapter.setItemClickListener(object : BookAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
                val booksData = dataList[position]

                // Start new Activity
                val intent = Intent(activity, ChapterActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("item", booksData)
                activity?.startActivity(intent)

                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })

    }

private fun parseJson(jsonData: String) {
        try {
            val jsonObjMain = JSONObject(jsonData)
            val jsonArray = jsonObjMain.getJSONArray("items")

            for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                val jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                val bookName = jsonObj.getString("bookName")
                val imageUrl = jsonObj.getString("imageUrl")
                val items: ArrayList<ChapterData> = ArrayList()
                val jsonArray2 = jsonObj.getJSONArray("content")
                for (j in 0 until jsonArray2.length()) {
                    val jsonObj2 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(j)
                    val chapterName = jsonObj2.getString("chapterName")
                    val detailList = java.util.ArrayList<String>()
                    val jsonArray3 = jsonObj2.getJSONArray("details")
                    for (k in 0 until jsonArray3.length()) {
                        val details = jsonArray3[k].toString()
                        detailList.add(details)
                    }
                    items.add(ChapterData(chapterName))
                }

                dataList.add(BooksData(bookName, imageUrl))
            }
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

//        hideLoader()
        bookAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

Chapter Activity (Second Activty)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chapter)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.chapterActivity)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets

        }
        chapList = ArrayList()
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chapterRecyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
        chapAdapter = ChapterAdapter(this, chapList)
        recyclerView.adapter = chapAdapter
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        initVar()
        initListener()

    }

private fun initVar() {
        mActivity = this@ChapterActivity
        mContext = mActivity.applicationContext

        val intent = intent
        if (intent != null) {
            mContent = intent.getParcelableExtra("item")!!
            chapList = mContent.items
        }

    }

ChapterData (data class for Chpater Activity )
data class ChapterData(var chapterName: String?) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(parcel.readString()) {
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(chapterName)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<ChapterData> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): ChapterData {
            return ChapterData(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<ChapterData?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}

